# Rendering dynamic data using chart.js

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, chart.js

I am trying to generate a graph using chart.js . To draw the graph I am using a model and sending the data through a controller. I am getting the following error:

> ```
> chartjs.init.js:3 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'getContext' of null
>     at HTMLDocument.<anonymous> (chartjs.init.js:3)
>     at f (jquery.js:1026)
>     at Object.fireWith [as resolveWith] (jquery.js:1138)
>     at Function.ready (jquery.js:427)
>     at HTMLDocument.xt (jquery.js:97)
> (anonymous) @ chartjs.init.js:3
> f @ jquery.js:1026
> fireWith @ jquery.js:1138
> ready @ jquery.js:427
> xt @ jquery.js:97
> ```

I read the other answers available & all are pointing to the problem that the chart is being rendered before the script. However  tried all the solutions and ended up with same error. Need help.

Also need help regarding the logic I have used.

Controller:

```
 public JsonResult BarChart()
        {
            List<DatapointLine> dataPoints = new List<DatapointLine>{
                new DatapointLine(10, 30),
                new DatapointLine(20, 40),
                new DatapointLine(30, 50),
                new DatapointLine(40, 60),
                new DatapointLine(50, 0),
            };

            ViewBag.DataPoints = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(dataPoints);

            return Json(dataPoints, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
```

Model:

```
public class DatapointLine
    {
        public DatapointLine(double x, double y)
        {
            this.X = x;
            this.Y = y;
        }

        // setting the name to be used when serializing to JSON.
        [DataMember(Name = "x")]
        public Nullable<double> X = null;

        //setting the name to be used whenserializing to JSON.
        [DataMember(Name = "y")]
        public Nullable<double> Y = null;
    }
```

View:

```
@{
    Layout = null;
}


<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/morris.js/0.5.1/morris.css">

</head>
<body>
    <div class="row">
        <canvas id="myChart"></canvas>
    </div>

</body>
</html>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- Chart JS -->
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Content/plugins/bower_components/Chart.js/chartjs.init.js")"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Content/plugins/bower_components/Chart.js/Chart.min.js")"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

        $(function() {
            var data = getData();
            AutoFollow(data);
        });

        function getData() {
            var dateValue = [];
            var countValue = [];
            $.ajax({
                url: "/Supernethome/BarChart",
                dataType: 'json',
                async: false
            }).done(function(data) {
                data.forEach(function(obj) {
                    dateValue.push(obj.X);
                    countValue.push(obj.Y);
                });
            });
            return {
                dateValue: dateValue,
                countValue: countValue
            };
        }
           function AutoFollow(data) {
            var ctx = this.find("#myChart").getContext('2d');
            var myChart = new Chart(ctx,
                {
                    type: 'bar',
                    data: {
                        labels: data.dateValue, // here i want to show my date value
                        datasets: [
                            {
                                label: 'AutoFollow',
                                data: data.countValue, // here show my total count date wise
                                backgroundColor: "rgba(153,255,51,1)"
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                });
        }

</script>
@*<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/raphael/2.1.0/raphael-min.js"></script>
  <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/morris.js/0.5.1/morris.min.js"></script>*@
```

Please suggest pitfalls and better ways to do the same.
Thanks a ton:)

Comment: I had a pretty much the same error when using chart.js a few months back. Not so much a problem with chart.js but more so their documentation. Try removing the `.getContext('2d')` from the `AutoFollow` fn

Comment: @harry It seems more likely to me that the issue is trying to find an element in the DOM (`#myChart`) before the DOM element is available. I imagine wrapping it all in [`$(document).ready(function() { // code here });`](https://api.jquery.com/ready/) would fix the issue

Comment: @harryparkdotio Hi tried it but still the error persists:).Would you say there is something wrong with the data being passed?

Comment: @John Hi tried that too ,but did not work,found a solution saying using `this.find("#myChart") ` instead of `document.getElementById("myChart")` and `documet.ready(function(){});` would work. But have the same error.